How can I prevent this exception from stopping the rest of the execution?
Backstory: I am providing students a skeleton of a dll file. In this file, there will be methods that the students need to fill in using .NET C#.
The students will take their compiled dll file and put put it in my "See how you're doing" Application that checks all methods for everything they should have and gives them a percentage of completion.
In my "See how you're doing" Application, for each potentially missing/broken content, I have a try/catch block that either executes successfully and adds a true value to a list of booleans that holds their score for any given class/struct, or it catches an error and adds a false when the criteria hasn't been met or an error is thrown. It looks like this:
List<bool> testResults;

testResults = new List<bool>(); 
Print("Starting Engine Tools testing.\n");

try 
{ 
    EngineTools.Print("Testing Print\n");
    testResults.Add(true); 
} catch (Exception ex)
{
    Print("Print Method in EngineTools Failed");
    testResults.Add(false);
}

Normally, this code and the "See how you're doing" program works as it should when using a good dll file. However, when I replace the good dll with a bad dll (it has basically everything removed from it, who knows what students will throw at this...) the program gets to the first (and only) attempt at running EngineTools.Print(object message) and throws:
"Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void GameEngine.EngineTools.Print(System.Object)'."

Completely reasonable since I removed the method from the dll for testing... except for the part where it should be handled by the try/catch statement, but it instead stops the program execution and doesn't continue or execute to the following tests. I know it doesn't continue execution because there's a score tally at the end of the program's execution and it doesn't show.
Is there something I'm overlooking? It should see that the method doesn't exist, move to the catch block, add a false to the test results, then move on to the next test, right?

Can you please provide a [mre]? Also you can use reflection beforehand to check if dll contains needed methods.

You would need to nest it another level, to prevent the JITter from throwning an exception the first time it sees your calling method. I'd advise you to instead use reflection to attempt to find and call this method, as that is more easily catchable.

@GuruStron I was able to make an MRE, but was able to implement it using Reflection as you suggested. If you think I should post the code for the MRE I will, but I'm not sure it's necessary.
Would you mind submitting your response as an answer so I can accept it?
Edit: Nevermind, question was closed.

@Fr0z3n5un glad that suggestion worked for you!
